# assign date from mysql table to input date field

Tags: php

In mysql table date is stored in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format

I want to show on php form in format of dd/mm/yyyy input field type date

I tried following code ... not working

```
$pddt = date_format( date_create($row['invdt']), 'd/m/Y' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `date()` function with PHP `strtotime()` function.

```
$pddt = date("d/m/Y",strtotime($row['invdt']));
```

Comment: still not working for code <td align="left"><input type="date" maxlength="10" size="10" name="txtddt" value="<?php echo  $pddt; ?>"/>, but worked for code <td align="left"><input type="text" maxlength="10" size="10" name="txtddt" value="<?php echo  $pddt; ?>"/> .. I want to get proper date, if invalid message

Comment: Where it is not working? Put your code in question where date is not working